# Unable to use bluetooth on my device

Tags: debian, bluetooth, firmware

**Problem**

I'm unable to use bluetooth. During the boot, I get this error:

```
usb 1-1.1: firmware: failed to load ar3k/AthrBT_0x01020200.dfu (-2)
Bluetooth: Loading patch file failed
```

Laptop: Asus x201e
OS: Debian 9.2.1 Mate

**What I've tried**

https://askubuntu.com/questions/574312/why-bluetooth-or-usb-3-0-fails-to-load-during-booting

```
echo "blacklist ath3k" | sudo tee /etc/modrobe.d/ath3k.conf
```

get this

```
debian@debian:~$ echo "blacklist ath3k" | sudo tee /etc/modrobe.d/ath3k.conf
tee: /etc/modrobe.d/ath3k.conf: No such file or directory
blacklist ath3k
```

also I've tried this:

```
sudo apt install firmware-atheros
```

output:

E: Unable to locate package firmware-atheros

I've also tried those instructions to build the firmware
https://wiki.debian.org/ath9k_htc/open_firmware

December 29th, 2017 Edit: I still have that issue unresolved.

Comment: Try `modprobe.d` instead of `modrobe.d`. Otherwise, I've got no idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried that and I don't get error while booting. However, I'm still unable to use my bluetooth. Blueman gives me "no adapters found" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> E: Unable to locate package firmware-atheros

The [`firmware-atheros`](https://packages.debian.org/fr/stretch/firmware-atheros) is a non-free software , you should have the `non-free` component to your `sources.list`.

Edit your sources.list (as root):

```
apt edit-sources
```

This is a sample `sources.list`( [debian wiki : SourcesList](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList)):

```
deb  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free

deb  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

Save then run :

```
apt update
apt install firmware-atheros
```

The package `firmware-atheros` provide the `ath3k` driver as the description say:

> This package contains the binary firmware for USB wireless network and Bluetooth cards supported by the ar5523, **ath3k**, ath6kl_sdio, ath6kl_usb, ath9k_htc or ath10k drivers.

To load the driver:

```
modprobe -v ath3k
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem on an Asus X200CA. This is what I had to do to get it to work.

Install firmware-atheros from non-free repo and GNOME Blueman - KDE's Bluetooth Manager is broken and fails to add devices.
`apt install firmware-atheros blueman`

If you do not have non-free then add it to /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free

Blacklist ath3k temporarily
`touch /etc/modprobe.d/ath3k.conf`
blacklist ath3k

Remove ath3k module
`rmmod ath3k`

Add `InitiallyPowered=true` to /etc/bluetooth/main.conf

Reboot - BlueTooth will not work on this reboot

Remove the temporary Module blacklist
rm /etc/modprobe.d/ath3k.conf

Load the ath3k module
modprobe ath3k

reboot - bluetooth should work

`rfkill list` - should say "No" "No"

If not run: `rfkill 1 unblock`

`hciconfig` - should say "up running"

if not run: `hciconfig hci0 up`